# How can I subtract two local macros containing variable names in Stata?

Tags: stata, local-variables

Imagine you have a list of variable names A,B,C,D,E saved in a local macro:

```
loc l1 "A B C D E"
```

You also have a different list of variable names A,C saved in a different macro:

```
loc l2 "A C"
```

How would you get the (set) difference of those, namely, a list of variable names B,D,E?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
local l1  "A B C D E"
local l2 "A C"
local l3 : list l1 - l2
di "`l3'"
```

for more see: [help extended fcn](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?extended_fcn), and especially [help macrolists](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?macrolists).